# Interpretation of a statement that I think I can prove by mathematical induction

Tags: proof-verification, induction, learning

I want to prove by mathematical induction the following statement: for any sequence (a_k) of non negative real numbers holds that:

$$(1+a1)(1+a2)...(1+a_n) >= 1 + a_1 + a_2 + ... a_n$$

I think this statement verbally translates as: the products of the sum of any positive real number with 1 is greater than or equal to the sum between 1 and the positive real numbers chosen.

**Indeed, I have a doubt now. Do the indices of the letters $a$ tell me that inside any parenthesis can be or should be chosen a different real number?**.

If yes, I would be a bit in trouble in writing the base case - or might I skip it, in some circumstances? - otherwise, since that we now deal with positive real numbers - a superset with respect to the natural numbers - I think that I could choose zero for the base case - perhaps, **I should** choose zero - as it is the first non negative real number! Obviously, you can disprove my statement.

However, zero holds for the base case, because we would end up with 1 = 1 - but I am not considering the different indices of the letters $a$, **which is my first doubt**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The base case is $n=1$ because your first available subscript is $1$. There is no $a_0$. So base case, $n=1$ you must show that $(1+a_1) \geq 1 + a_1$, which is trivial. Then prove induction statement for $n+1$, which states 
\begin{equation}
\prod_{i=1}^{n+1} (1+a_i) \geq 1 + \sum_{i=1}^{n+1} a_i
\end{equation}
But
\begin{equation}
\prod_{i=1}^{n+1} (1+a_i) = \prod_{i=1}^{n} (1+a_i) \cdot (1+a_{n+1})
\end{equation}
And
\begin{equation}
1 + \sum_{i=1}^{n+1} a_i = 1 + \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i + a_{n+1}
\end{equation}

Consider $\prod_{i=1}^{n} (1+a_i) \cdot (1+a_{n+1})$. Rewrite using distributive law such that
\begin{equation}
\prod_{i=1}^{n} (1+a_i) \cdot (1+a_{n+1})=\prod_{i=1}^{n} (1+a_i) + a_{n+1} \cdot \prod_{i=1}^{n} (1+a_i)
\end{equation}

Since you are using mathematical induction, you are assuming that your induction statement
\begin{equation}
P(n):\prod_{i=1}^{n} (1+a_i) \geq 1 + \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i
\end{equation}
is true. Now add $a_{n+1} \cdot \prod_{i=1}^{n} (1+a_i)$ to both sides of the inequality such that
\begin{equation}
\prod_{i=1}^{n} (1+a_i) +a_{n+1} \cdot \prod_{i=1}^{n} (1+a_i) \geq 1 + \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i + a_{n+1} \cdot \prod_{i=1}^{n} (1+a_i)
\end{equation}

The left-hand side of this inequality is just
\begin{equation}
\prod_{i=1}^{n+1} (1+a_i)
\end{equation}

as was shown near the start. Upon substitution into the inequality,

\begin{equation}
\prod_{i=1}^{n+1} (1+a_i) \geq 1 + \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i + a_{n+1} \cdot \prod_{i=1}^{n} (1+a_i)
\end{equation}

*Now*, since every $a_i$ is a nonnegative integer, $1+a_i\geq 1$. More specifically,

\begin{equation}
\prod_{i=1}^{n} (1+a_i) \geq 1 \implies a_{n+1} \cdot \prod_{i=1}^{n} (1+a_i) \geq a_{n+1}
\end{equation}

Thus,

\begin{equation}
\prod_{i=1}^{n+1} (1+a_i) \geq 1 + \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i + a_{n+1} \cdot \prod_{i=1}^{n} (1+a_i) \geq 1 + \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i + a_{n+1} \\
\prod_{i=1}^{n+1} (1+a_i) \geq 1 + \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i + a_{n+1} =1 + \sum_{i=1}^{n+1} a_i \\
\prod_{i=1}^{n+1} (1+a_i) \geq 1 + \sum_{i=1}^{n+1} a_i
\end{equation}

*Done*

Comment: Thank you! I have a question, actually. but does the $n$ upon the product symbol stand for natural number? But positive real number set is a wider set than natural numbers set - it contains also the positive irrationals, for instance.

Comment: perhaps, I get it. Do the subscripts 1, 2...etc. tell us that we have to choose natural numbers? But, if yes, why the text speaks about positive real numbers instead than natural numbers just?

Comment: of course, my question is about also the $n+1$ upon the sigma.

Comment: The subscripts are natural numbers simply as a way to distinguish different elements ($a_1$, $a_2$, $\cdots$) but the elements themselves are positive real numbers. You could label them in any way you wish, for example $a_{banana}$, or $a_{pineapple}$, etc... but the number that it represents is a positive real number. Does that make sense?

Comment: Is the proof already written in your final steps?

Comment: Editing to finish proof now.

Comment: I am honest. I feel that I would not be able to write this proof on my own...Surely, I have to get much more acquainted with mathematical language and logical-mathematical reasoning

Comment: It may help you to go over the technique of mathematical induction and try some simpler problems. This one was also a bit messy with the $\sum$ and $\prod$ notation, although it saves on writing. Try doing it out without collecting terms into a $\sum$ or $\prod$, it may help you see what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

Consider a sequence $a_n \geq 0$. Clearly $$a_1+1 \geq a_1+1.$$
Assume that for $k$ we have $$(1+a_1)(1+a_2) \cdots (1+a_k) \geq 1+a_1+a_2 + \cdots +a_k.$$
Now $$(1+a_1)(1+a_2) \cdots (1+a_k)(1+a_{k+1}) \geq \left( 1+a_1+a_2 + \cdots +a_k \right)(1+a_{k+1}) \\ \geq 1+a_1+a_2 + \cdots +a_k +a_{k+1}, $$
because the last expression is obtained by dropping some non-negative terms.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: Well it answers the question "Do the indices of the letters aa tell me that inside any parenthesis can be or should be chosen a different real number?" since the sequence $a_n \geq 0$ is arbitrary.